# ¿Es posible usar el verbo "sufrir" en oraciones que prescindan por completo de connotaciones negativas?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado

Hay un anuncio de televisión (emitido en España) que se puede ver desde 2016 que defiende la planificación familiar, aconsejando el uso de medios de prevención (preservativos, píldora y demás) y que está patrocinado por Durex. Y contiene la siguiente frase (negritas mías):

> Una de cada tres mujeres **sufrirá** a lo largo de su vida un embarazo no planificado.

Justo este fin de semana me di cuenta de una cosa. El uso del verbo *[sufrir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YfNZupH)* se suele entender como algo malo. Las dos primeras acepciones hablan de "sufrir un daño", aunque luego haya otras que "simplemente" signifiquen "llevar algo con paciencia". En todo caso, parece que el verbo *sufrir* lleva implícita una connotación negativa de un modo u otro.

¿Es un embarazo no planificado algo que se "sufra"? Me explico: mi mujer y yo hemos encargado nuestros dos niños a la ciencia. Tras más de una década sin usar medios de prevención ha tenido que ser así. Por tanto, un embarazo espontáneo ahora mismo para nosotros desde luego no estaría planificado, pero eso no quiere decir que lo vayamos a sufrir, sino todo lo contrario. Y como este me imagino que habrá muchos casos de embarazos no planificados que más que "sufrirlos" sean una alegría.

Así pues, para mí la frase es incoherente y debería ser redactada de otra forma, aunque eso es una opinión subjetiva que simplemente quería compartir con vosotros. Pero sin entrar en debates subjetivos, centrémonos en el verbo *sufrir*: ¿es posible redactar frases que usen este verbo que prescindan por completo de las connotaciones negativas?

Comment: A mi me parece un tema demasiado subjetivo, probablemente *off-topic*, hay para quien pueda ser un sufrimiento. Hablas de tu caso pero cada persona o pareja es un mundo, puede ser un embarazo a una edad avanzada que sea peligroso, una mujer sin pareja estable y se vea sola en la situación o que simplemente no quiera tener hijos. No sé, se me ocurren varios motivos que pueden hacer que sea un sufrimiento para algunas personas.

Comment: @blonfu por supuesto. Pero precisamente por eso no quiero entrar en temas subjetivos, sino solo centrarme en el uso del verbo "sufrir" en la frase tal y como está planteada. Simplemente quise exponer que "no planificado" no siempre quiere decir "no deseado", y dar un ejemplo práctico de ello.

Comment: @Charlie Me parece que, para evitar un verbo simple como "tener", se buscó un verbo un poco más sofisticado. Aunque el DRAE no lo contempla, "sufrir" a veces se usa como "pasar por" o "experimentar", como es el caso de "sufrir cambios". Cualquiera de estas opciones me parece válida en lugar de "sufrir", que puede ser relacionado con algo negativo.

Comment: Creo que te estas dejando ofender por la connotacion negativa de la palabra, cuando el significa de la palabra es mas acercado al "soportar"

Comment: @walen está claro que esta es otra de mis famosas preguntas en el límite del off-topic. :-D La respuesta de pablodf76 va en la línea de lo que yo esperaba, y que no sé si a lo mejor así la pregunta evitaría su cierre: ¿en qué casos se puede usar "sufrir" sin que entren en juego connotaciones negativas? ¿Te parecería mejor?

Comment: @walen (y demás) he cambiado completamente el planteamiento de la pregunta. Espero que esto ayude a atraer más votos y respuestas. :-)

Comment: Filosofia ! simbolismo ! semiotica ! , el mensaje oculto de las palabras, lo que el escritor trata de decir ! vayan al Meta a ver mi pregunta sobre preguntas acerca del uso literario del español. este es un claro ejemplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi granito de arena:

> Para convertirse en mariposa, la oruga **sufre** un impresionante proceso llamado metamorfosis.
>
> <sub>Extraído de: [¿Cómo se trasforman las orugas en mariposas?](http://zoouniverso.blogspot.com/2012/03/como-se-trasforman-las-orugas-en.html)</sub>
>
> A diferencia del camaleón, la oruga **sufre** un proceso lento de metamorfosis donde, pese a su forma inicial,  en sus genes está implícita la mariposa, aunque sin embargo deba primero evolucionar de oruga a crisálida para al fin completar el proceso que la vuelve adulta.
>
> <sub>Extraído de: [¿El camaleón o la oruga?](http://www.jmlucero.com/comunicacion/el-camaleon-o-la-oruga-una-breve-analogia-para-repensar-el-cambio-en-los-medios-y-el-periodismo-en-internet)</sub>

El uso de "sufrir" en este contexto no implica necesariamente que la oruga *sufra* debido a los cambios (en el sentido de las muchas acepciones de [sufrir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YfNZupH): de lo físico a lo moral o a permitir/resistir/tolerar). El uso en este contexto tiene el sentido de [experimentar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HIutMRm) (Recibir una modificación, cambio o mudanza).

Ciertamente no es el sentido en la frase de ejemplo, pero esto sirve de muestra para ver usado `sufrir` con connotaciones diferentes a las dadas por las definiciones del diccionario.

Esto es por supuesto subjetivo. Al decir que "la oruga **sufre** una metamorfosis" le damos un carácter más catárquico al asunto. La transformación puede no ser placentera, pero acaba convertida en bellísima mariposa. Si por el contrario decimos que "la oruga **experimenta** una metamorfosis", hay menos (o ninguna) connotación de "la transformación es incómoda" en algún sentido.

Por tanto, el uso de "sufrir" con el sentido que tiene `experimentar` (ser el receptor de cierta experiencia) va cargado de las connotaciones negativas del verbo sufrir (aunque esas connotaciones, son subjetivas, especialmente en distintos contextos).

Y, porque todos no los estamos preguntando llegados a este punto, no se sabe si la oruga sufre dolor con su metamorfosis.

De forma análoga, se puede decir que un compuesto químico (que no creo que sea capaz de experimentar dolor) puede "[sufrir una transformación química](https://books.google.com/books?id=dxxBtJF_IXYC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=planta%20sufre%20transformaciones&source=bl&ots=qn2a3XZajf&sig=n-PQ29idkjegd9TduBHw1mImngg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj95N-FhIXYAhVJkRQKHQLUDakQ6AEIQTAI#v=onepage&q=planta%20sufre%20transformaciones&f=false)". Aquí entiendo que la connotación, si acaso, es más bien que "el cambio llega impuesto".

Creo que no es del todo objetivo, pero considero que podría argumentarse que hay usos de "sufrir", cuando se usa como sinónimo de experimentar, en los que la connotación puede no ser *tan* negativa, pero en cualquier caso al elegir esa palabra sobre otras le das el matiz negativo a la acción (molesto, no deseado, impuesto, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Creo que en el anuncio se está dando por hecho que la mayoría de los embarazos no planificados (¿no está mejor dicho *planeados*?) son de hecho embarazos no deseados, como probablemente sea el caso. De todas formas sería interesante conocer las estadísticas para no confundir las categorías.

Quizá pueda tenerse por "no planificado" un embarazo como el que busca el OP, que es buscado pero que en verdad no se sabe si se producirá dentro de los plazos razonables o esperables para un embarazo. Es decir, se lo busca pero dadas las circunstancias no se lo puede planificar. Obviamente esto no justifica el uso de *sufrir*. Un embarazo no buscado y no planificado puede causar algún trastorno pero no necesariamente es algo para sufrir (salvo en la acepción de "permitir, aceptar").

O quizá haya que darle la vuelta a la lógica de la frase: si una mujer *sufre* un embarazo no planificado, es precisamente porque el mismo fue no deseado.

*Experimentar* habría sido mejor, ya que las connotaciones negativas de *sufrir* son inescapables, incluso cuando el sujeto es abstracto (*El PIB sufrió una importante caída*; *La profesión periodística ha sufrido un gran desprestigio*; etc.). He estado buscando ejemplos donde *sufrir* tenga un significado al menos neutral y no he encontrado ninguno.

Comment: Creo que precisamente se usa la palabra *sufrir* para darle un sentido negativo ya que el anuncio es de una marca de preservativos si no recuerdo mal, en cualquier caso trata de métodos anticonceptivos y quieren destacar lo malo de quedar embarazada sin desearlo.

Comment: He cambiado el planteamiento de la pregunta porque estaba generando dudas acerca de su validez. Tu respuesta sigue siendo válida dado que la última parte básicamente responde al nuevo planteamiento, pero te aviso por si quieres alterar algo de la redacción. Lamento las molestias.

Comment: No hay problema. Añado un párrafo que no altera sustancialmente la respuesta.